# Qu'est-ce que le mot « tournant » dans la phrase « se trouver à un tournant » veut dire?

Tags: expressions, sens, usage

> Il me semblait, ce matin-là, mais certainement me trompais-je, que la littérature, sous la forme usuelle, se trouvait à un tournant.

La source citée est *Héros, personnages et magiciens* par [Vincent Ravalec](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_Ravalec) (à ne pas confondre avec [*Voyageurs et Magiciens*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyageurs_et_Magiciens) par [Khyentse_Norbu](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khyentse_Norbu) :-) )

Est-ce que cela signifie que la littérature changeait sa course de développement habituel, ou s'agissait-il d'une dégradation putative des belles-lettres?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le terme *tournant* est ici synonyme de *rupture* ou de *fort changement*.

Cette phrase indique qu'un certain événement a significativement changé la littérature.

Seul le contexte permet de déterminer si ce changement est bénéfique ou non. Le terme *tournant* est généralement porteur d'espoir, mais ce n'est pas toujours le cas.

Answer (score 3):

Voir [tournant](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/tournant) sens B du substantif.  Plus que l'aspect positif ou négatif, c'est l'incertitude de ce sur quoi on débouche qui me semble être la notion dominante (incertitude présente aussi dans l'expression « être à un carrefour », mais cette expression suppose en plus un ou des choix à faire).