# Conveying "Jumping the shark"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Reading a review for the new Fast and Furious film I came across the (American) idiom "jumping the shark".

> Jumping the shark is an idiom used to describe the moment of a
> misguided attempt at generating new publicity for something once, but
> no longer, widely popular; the attempt serves instead to highlight the
> irrelevance of what it intends to promote. This is especially
> applicable to television series or other entertainment outlets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark

I was curious if there is an idiomatic way to convey "jumping the shark" as below

> “This is Trump’s jump the shark moment,” John Feehery, a former key aide to Republican congressional leaders, told the Daily News. “It’s all downhill from here.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions, although none is a direct replacement:

- *Atteindre son [**apogée**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apog%C3%A9e)*: A place from where you can only go downhill. However, unlike "jump the shark", the term is positive.
- *[**Tournant**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/quest-ce-que-le-mot-tournant-dans-la-phrase-se-trouver-%C3%A0-un-tournant-ve/6768#6768)*: A significant change in direction. Might be positive or negative.
- *[**Partir en vrille**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partir_en_vrille)*: Lose control.

“This is Trump’s jump the shark moment,...” might then be translated to:

> *C'est un tournant pour D. Trump,...*

> *À partir de là, D. Trump a commencé à partir en vrille,...*

Comment: You shouldn't accept my or any answer too fast. Someone might came later with a better idea. Of course, an OP can still un-accept a reply in such case but the fact an answer is accepted might discourage others from providing their own answers.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the "jumping the sharks" wikipedia page, and @jiliagre's answer, here are other examples I would like to add (I am not completely sure about my translations though) :

- A un moment donné, il ne savaient plus quoi inventer

At one moment, they ran out of ideas [hence : they started doing stupid things].

- A partir de là, c'est devenu n'importe quoi.

From that point, it became nonsense.

- A partir de ce jour là, ça a viré au (grand) n'importe quoi.

From this day, it went (full) nonsense.